# `MouseMove A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight` loses precision

Tags: mouse, resolution, autohotkey, cursor, mouse-cursor

Quote from [the documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen):

> `A_ScreenWidth`, `A_ScreenHeight`: The width and height of the primary monitor, in pixels (e.g. 1024 and 768).

I expected the following code to move the cursor tip at the right bottom of the screen, for example, if the screen's resolution is 1920 x 1080, then the cursor tip should be moved to `(1920, 1080)`, but in reality, the cursor tip was moved to `(1919, 1079)`, does anyone know why?

```
CoordMode Mouse

MouseMove A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the coodinates start from `(0, 0)` instead of `(1, 1)`, therefore `(0, 0)` to `(1919, 1079)`, not `(1, 1)` to `(1920, 1080)`.